# libEchoNest C++ QtCore Library Linking Problems

Tags: c++, qt, compilation

I'm having problems linking the QtCore and QtNetwork libraries when I compile a c++ file that includes libechonest. Specifically:

```
alexcannon$ gcc -g -Wall -o geoEchoNest geoEchoNest.cc -lechonest -lQtCore -lQtNetwork
In file included from geoEchoNest.c:6:
In file included from /usr/local/include/echonest/Artist.h:22:
In file included from /usr/local/include/echonest/ArtistTypes.h:21:
/usr/local/include/echonest/Util.h:22:10: fatal error: 'QDebug' file not found
#include <QDebug>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I even tried adding `-L/usr/local/lib/QtCore.framework/` in case QtCore wasn't in the     "standard path" (whatever that means):

```
alexcannon$ gcc -g -Wall -o geoEchoNest geoEchoNest.cc -lechonest -    L/usr/local/lib/QtCore.framework/ -lQtCore -lQtNetwork
```

...with the same results. What am I doing wrong here? I installed Qt in /usr/local/ as well as QJSON before installing libechonest via the instructions in the README:

```
alexcannon$ cat README 

libechonest
===========

libechonest is a collection of C++/Qt classes designed to make a developer's life
easy when trying to use the APIs provided by The Echo Nest. More information about
the APIs can be found here:

http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/

libechonest is developed by Leo Franchi (lfranchi@kde.org), and is available at KDE's projects page,
  https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/libs/libechonest .
  Review request are accepted at http://git.reviewboard.kde.org under the compenent libechonest, and
   API comments, and more are appreciated.

Dependencies
============

    * Qt, only the QtCore, QtNetwork and QtTest modules (www.qtsoftware.com)
    * CMake, Kitware's open source build system (http://cmake.org)
    * QJson (http://qjson.sourceforge.net/).

Installing
==========

mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/desired/install ..
make
make install

Using libechonest
===============
The c++ API is meant to be as close to the Echo Nest API as possible. All Echo Nest
API functions have been copied into their respective c++ equivalents, and string values
converted to enums where reasonable.

See the unit tests in tests/ for examples on how to use the classes.

You need an API key from http://developer.echonest.com to use this library. Set your API key
 with Echonest::Config::instance()->setAPIKey().

You can also set your own custom QNetworkAccessManager-derived class with Config::setNetworkAccessManager();

Your link line needs to include the following:

    -lechonest -lQtCore -lQtNetwork

Thank you for tuning in!

leo

-------
This README, and libechonest in general, is inspired by Max Howell's liblastfm,
 at http://www.github.com/mxcl/liblastfm.
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is not a problem with linking but with compilation. The compiler error states he cannot find the included QDebug. That is not very surprising as you don't provide any include path. (with -I)
Why do you not follow the installation instructions? The build system (CMake) will do that for you. You even posted the installation instructions in your question. Follow these, they will not only install but also configure and build your library.

Comment: "I installed Qt in /usr/local/ as well as QJSON before installing libechonest via the instructions in the README"


I did follow these instructions. What in my question makes you think I didn't? Have I said I'm doing anything not in line with the README instructions?

Thanks.

Comment: Bacause you executed gcc directly and in a wrong fashion (missing -I). If you followed the instructions, you would have executed `cmake` and this would give you either an error that you would have written in your question or otherwise would have executed `make`. And the Makefile would contain by far more complex commands to compile your library.
After `make install` you should find the library in `/path/to/desired/install/lib`.

Comment: I'm confused (clearly). Correct me if I'm wrong, but the instructions in the README (which, again, I did follow, `cmake` and all) are for constructing the makefiles, etc. for compiling and installing the libechonest library. Now after having performed these instructions to _install_ the library, I'm trying to compile (with gcc and -l) a C++ file that _includes_ this library, which is where I'm running into problems. Is that also how you understand the problem? Or is there some misunderstanding here?

Comment: Ah ok, I was confused by _I'm having problems linking the QtCore and QtNetwork libraries when I compile libechonest._
1) Use g++ instead gcc for compiling C++. That should not be your problem.
2) Add the headers for QtCore, QtNetwork, and libechonest. You only added libraries for the linker (with -L and -l (lowercase L)). But you missed to add the headers (with -I (uppercase i)).

Comment: Sweet, thanks. Doing `g++ -g -Wall -o geoEchoNest geoEchoNest.cpp -lechonest -lQtCore -lQtNetwork -I/usr/local/include/echonest -I/usr/local/include/QtCore -I/usr/local/include/QtNetwork` seems to have worked! Now on to debugging the other slew of compiler errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the headers for QtCore, QtNetwork, and libechonest. You only added libraries for the linker (with `-L` and `-l` (lowercase L)), but you missed to add the headers (with `-I` (uppercase i)).